# Kalman filter - In java - operate method/API

Tags: java, apache, kalman-filter

I came across this very good tutorial on Kalman for vehicle speed - "http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/filter.html. But, I am still unable to resolve or identify what is - "operate" how can I use it? Is it using operate API? Can somebody give me reference?

I have tried using this:

// x = A * x + p_noise
x = A.operate(x).add(pNoise);

So what does this operate stand for - matrix and vector multiplication?

Thanks

Comment: Please describe exactly what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It clearly explains it on the previous line's comment:

```
// x = A * x + p_noise
x = A.operate(x).add(pNoise);
```

Given that A is a matrix and x is a vector, it is matrix-vector multiplication. [You can find the JavaDoc here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/linear/RealMatrix.html#operate(double[])).